# Django Rest Framework - POST request, "This list may not be empty" when list is not empty?

Tags: django, post, curl, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest framework to set up my own API and having trouble getting the POST method to work correctly. I use the curl command:

```
 curl --form "fileupload=@exampleteam.json" 127.0.0.1:8000/teams/ > error.html
```

to hit my api with the json file exampleteam.json formatted like such:

```
[{"id":3,"name":"newTeam","members":["mem1", "mem2"],"services_used":["service1"]}]
```

So basically, what I want is to create a new team that has the members mem1 and mem2 and utilizes service 1. newTeam, mem1, mem2, and service1 all exist in my database already.

What I get back is this strange html that tells me there isn't any info in my list, and the database does not reflect that I ever made the request. This is what is piped into error.html:

```
{"members":["This list may not be empty."],"services_used":["This list may not be empty."]}
```

This is strange to me, the members list is clearly not empty and neither is the services_used list in my request. I'm reasonably confident that the error is either where I defined my POST method, or is a problem with my models, though after messing with those I still cannot find the issue. Below are both files.

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def team_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        teams = Team.objects.all()
        serializer = TeamSerializer(teams, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = TeamSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and the associated models from models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, default="")
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Member')
    services_used = models.ManyToManyField('Service')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, default="")
    services_used = models.ManyToManyField('Service')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.name)
```

and the TeamSerializer class:

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'members','services_used')
```

Why is the POST request not updating the database correctly?

Comment: Can you also add TeamSerializer class?

Comment: @MujGabriel added the TeamSerializer class. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing if you want to create a list of objects then instantiate serializer with parameter many

```
...
elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = TeamSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
```

Second thing, members and services should be a list of integers (PK of already existing objects), not strings.

```
"members":[1, 2],"services_used":[1]
```

If you send a file instead of json as payload, you will need to do this trick to make it work:

```
import json 

...
elif request.method == 'POST':
    # 'fileupload' is id specified in curl argument
    data = json.loads(request.data['fileupload'].read())
    serializer = TeamSerializer(data=data, many=True)
```

Comment: i changed the request method and the json I'm sending as you indicated but now what happens is [] is piped into error.html and the database still is not updated.

Comment: @Ragnyll are you sure you are using curl right? I am not really an expert using curl command but you are sending a file instead of a json. Try this: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '[{"id":3,"name":"newTeam","members":[1, 2],"services_used":[1]}]' 127.0.0.1:8000/teams/ > error.html`

Comment: you were right about the use of curl flags. I thought I was using it for fileupload correctly but I guess not. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not working with instances as specified by Muj Gabriel's answer you can specify the serializer in your class' serializer with the `many=True` option, for example (classes might not really make sense, but it's just for example purposes):

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book


class ChapterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    books = BookSerializer(many=True)  # Allows us to create chapters without specifying book(s) straight away

    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
```